# Python selenium click button by class not working

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to click a button with its class but it throws an ElementNotInteractableException.
[Here is the website HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1eWO.jpg)

Here is the code I'm using

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)

driver.get('https://physionet.org/lightwave/?db=noneeg/1.0.0')

def get_spo2hr(subject):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='record']/option[text()='"+subject+"']").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id('ui-id-3').click()
    driver.find_element_by_id('viewann').click()
    driver.find_element_by_id('viewsig').click()
    driver.find_element_by_id('lwform').click()
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".fwd").click()
    driver.save_screenshot('screenie.png')
    

get_spo2hr('Subject10_SpO2HR')
```

Comment: Can you share the website url?

Comment: https://physionet.org/lightwave/?db=noneeg/1.0.0 Please select Subject10_SpO2HR
and change to tables tab to replicate the issue.

Comment: I should have read that line ```driver.get('https://physionet.org/lightwave/?db=noneeg/1.0.0')``` ... :)

Comment: @guest2341 This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing is (as said in other answers) the unstable css selector prefer xpath

But the main thing is that the div is overlapping the a item at the dom rendering
Just wait one second to wait until the dom loads:

```python
import time
time.sleep(1)
```

Example code:

```python
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://physionet.org/lightwave/?db=noneeg/1.0.0')

def get_spo2hr(subject):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='record']/option[text()='"+subject+"']").click()

    import time
    time.sleep(1)

    driver.find_element_by_id('ui-id-3').click()
    driver.find_element_by_id('viewann').click()
    driver.find_element_by_id('viewsig').click()
    driver.find_element_by_id('lwform').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div/div/form/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/button[3]').click()
    driver.save_screenshot('screenie.png')

get_spo2hr('Subject10_SpO2HR')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Its resolved now and I've learned a new thing :)

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer getting elements using their xpath, of course, in suitable situations. With that being said, I modified your code to find the forward button using its xpath and it works.

Here is the modified code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)

driver.get('https://physionet.org/lightwave/?db=noneeg/1.0.0')

def get_spo2hr(subject):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='record']/option[text()='" + subject + "']").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id('ui-id-3').click()
    driver.find_element_by_id('viewann').click()
    driver.find_element_by_id('viewsig').click()
    driver.find_element_by_id('lwform').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div/div/form/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/button[3]').click()
    driver.save_screenshot('screenie.png')


get_spo2hr('Subject10_SpO2HR')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think as exception mentioned adding a timer for the dom to load is the best way to handle this so I'm considering his answer as resolved.

Comment: Normally you want to use WebDriverWait but in this case you are not waiting for an element to be generated by JavaScript, you are waiting for the browser to render the overlapping correctly.